# filter an array on object keys not empty

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

I'm trying to filter an array of objects by an object keys that have a value not empty

```js
var collection = [
                      {
            "season": "ETE 18",
            "group": "GRBABY",
            "market": "ALL",
            "department": "ALL",
            "skuType": "ALL",
            "orderType": "ASE",
            "packagingType": "CI"
        },
        {
            "season": "ETE 18",
            "group": "MEN",
            "market": "ALL",
            "department": "ALL",
            "skuType": "ALL",
            "orderType": "ASE",
            "packagingType": "CI"
        },
        {
            "season": "ETE 18",
            "group": "GRBABY",
            "market": "NONE",
            "department": "ALL",
            "skuType": "ALL",
            "orderType": "ASE",
            "packagingType": "CI"
        },
                     ]

      var filterList = {season: "", group: "GRBABY", market: "ALL", department: "", 
          skuType: ""}

      var result = _.filter(collection , proPack => {
                          if (filterList.group !== '') {
                              return proPack.group === filterList.group;
                          } else {
                              return proPack;
                          }
                    });
                    
                    console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

This works for me for one filter but I'm unable to find a way to filter for all other keys when they have a value.

the result shoud be :

```
result = [
              {
    "season": "ETE 18",
    "group": "GRBABY",
    "market": "ALL",
    "department": "ALL",
    "skuType": "ALL",
    "orderType": "ASE",
    "packagingType": "CI"
} ]
```

Comment: it isn't 100% clear to me what the issue is

Comment: @PaulFitzgerald I added the snippet, result should filter on all keys and not just one key. I can't find a way to filter on all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the empty properties:

```js
var collection = [{
    "season": "ETE 18",
    "group": "GRBABY",
    "market": "ALL",
    "department": "ALL",
    "skuType": "ALL",
    "orderType": "ASE",
    "packagingType": "CI"
  },
  {
    "season": "ETE 18",
    "group": "MEN",
    "market": "ALL",
    "department": "ALL",
    "skuType": "ALL",
    "orderType": "ASE",
    "packagingType": "CI"
  },
  {
    "season": "ETE 18",
    "group": "GRBABY",
    "market": "NONE",
    "department": "ALL",
    "skuType": "ALL",
    "orderType": "ASE",
    "packagingType": "CI"
  }
]

var filterList = {season: "", group: "GRBABY", market: "ALL", department: "", 
          skuType: ""}
          
var filterList = _.omitBy(filterList, _.isEmpty)   // { group: "GRBABY", market: "ALL" }

var result = _.filter(collection, filterList)

console.log(filterList, result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You could code the removal of empty filters using omitBy: `let filters = _.omitBy(filterList, _.isEmpty);`

Comment: @Slai this works indeed if filterList object has only the two keys, but my filterList is an object model that has always all keys, some are valorised and some not. this why I need to filter only on keys having a value

Comment: Thanks @GruffBunny

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do what you want. You are ignoring keys in your `filterList` with empty values right?

```js
var collection = [
                      {
            "season": "ETE 18",
            "group": "GRBABY",
            "market": "ALL",
            "department": "ALL",
            "skuType": "ALL",
            "orderType": "ASE",
            "packagingType": "CI"
        },
        {
            "season": "ETE 18",
            "group": "MEN",
            "market": "ALL",
            "department": "ALL",
            "skuType": "ALL",
            "orderType": "ASE",
            "packagingType": "CI"
        },
        {
            "season": "ETE 18",
            "group": "GRBABY",
            "market": "NONE",
            "department": "ALL",
            "skuType": "ALL",
            "orderType": "ASE",
            "packagingType": "CI"
        },
                     ]

      var filterList = {season: "", group: "GRBABY", market: "ALL", department: "", 
          skuType: ""}

var doFilter = function(arr, filterObj) {
    return arr.filter(propack => {
        for (key in filterObj) {
            if (filterObj[key] && filterObj[key] !== propack[key]) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    });
};

console.log(doFilter(collection, filterList));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```